# !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsf, primefaces

We are developing a java maven project using jsf framework and all going fine ,we need to restart our eclipse oxygen   and suddely we got error in eclipse and we checked in project workspace log having below error

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2018-07-06 07:48:41.956
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.web.WebAppProvider.getImage(WebAppProvider.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.Web25LabelProvider.getImage(Web25LabelProvider.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.findImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getColumnImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider$StyledLabelProviderAdapter.getImage(NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:946)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1025)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2159)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.internalUpdate(StructuredViewer.java:2142)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.update(StructuredViewer.java:2083)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.update(ColumnViewer.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.update(CommonViewer.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.update(StructuredViewer.java:2027)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleLabelProviderChanged(StructuredViewer.java:1203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleLabelProviderChanged(CommonViewer.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer$1.labelProviderChanged(ContentViewer.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.BaseLabelProvider$1.run(BaseLabelProvider.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.BaseLabelProvider.fireLabelProviderChanged(BaseLabelProvider.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.lambda$0(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratorManager$1.run(DecoratorManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratorManager.fireListener(DecoratorManager.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$3.runInUIThread(DecorationScheduler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob.lambda$0(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3820)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

**versions**

- java 1.8
- tomcat 8.5
- primefaces 5.5
- jsf-impl 2.2.4
- jsf-api 2.2.4

we done project clean ,maven update and restart the eclipse all possible ways we tried

thanks in advance

Comment: This appears to be Eclipse bug [442762](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442762). Comments in the bug report suggest it is finally fixed in Eclipse Photon.

Comment: @greg-449 hi,but still Eclipse photon throws the same error